# How can I initialize my WPF Monogame ContentManager?

Tags: wpf, monogame

I have followed the [monogame wpf sample](https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples) and the old [XNA wpf sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicgrave/archive/2010/07/25/rendering-with-xna-framework-4-0-inside-of-a-wpf-application.aspx) to create a view in WPF with a loaded model through monogame (I'm also using mvvmlight but that shouldn't matter much I hope).

Everything else works except the contentManager I.e. Making a cube out of vertices is displayed fine with a local instance of GraphicsDevice

Depending on whether I use IntPtr.Zero or the actual window handle to create the instance of GraphicsDevice I get a different error and neither give many details so I don't know which I should persue...

When I use IntPtr.Zero

```
        _services = new ServiceContainer();
        _services.AddService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService), _graphicsDeviceService);
        ContentManager content = new ContentManager(_services, "");
        var model = content.Load<Model3D>("psp"); // At this line
```

I get an error about

```
"The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.TitleContainer' threw an exception."
Inner Exception: The process has no package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54)
```

But when I use the Actual WindowPointer I get this error

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'E:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XSITE2DEV\xSite2Dev\MvvmMonogameTest\bin\Debug\MvvmMonogameTest.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x71985144, on thread 0x5f38. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

In the GraphicsDeviceService creating the first instance of GraphicsDevice

I get my window pointer by using these methods

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a reference to the singleton instance.
/// </summary>
public static GraphicsDeviceService AddRef(int width, int height)
{
    var singletonInstance = SimpleIoc.Default.GetService(typeof(IGraphicsDeviceService)) as GraphicsDeviceService;

    // Increment the "how many controls sharing the device" reference count.
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _referenceCount) == 1)
    {
        // If this is the first control to start using the
        // device, we must create the device.
        singletonInstance.EnsureGraphicsDevice();
    }

    return singletonInstance;
}

private void EnsureGraphicsDevice()
{
    if (_graphicsDevice != null)
        return;

    //CreateDevice(IntPtr.Zero, 1, 1);
    CreateDevice(new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle, 1, 1);
}

private void CreateDevice(IntPtr windowHandle, int width, int height)
{
    _parameters = new PresentationParameters
    {
        BackBufferWidth = Math.Max(width, 1),
        BackBufferHeight = Math.Max(height, 1),
        BackBufferFormat = SurfaceFormat.Color,
        DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24,
        DeviceWindowHandle = windowHandle,
        PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate,
        IsFullScreen = false
    };

    _graphicsDevice = new GraphicsDevice(
        GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter,
        GraphicsProfile.HiDef,
        _parameters);

    if (DeviceCreated != null)
        DeviceCreated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

I feel like using the actual window pointer is the correct approach but the error has no further details so I can't go anywhere with it..

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar error while using an implementation as yours. For me, it occured because `Game.Instance` was null and if you look up the source code of `GraphicsDevice` at the MonoGame source, you will find that the constructor depends on that (at least in OpenGL).This link could be helpful:

https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/2586

Basically, you have two options:

- Bringing a `Game` in (e.g. inheriting from Game) will set Game.Instance in the constructor
- Customizing the MonoGame Source to use your Handle

By the way I am not 100% sure that this is what is causing your error message.

I know that this post is old and I am quite likely too late but this may be helpful for anybody else who is experiencing this error.